# Create time from two array

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays having hour and minute   in PHP ,I want to create the all combination of time from that array.

```
$hour   =array('1','5');
$minut  =array('30','45');
```

I have done it with

```
$result=array();
 foreach($hour as $h){
    foreach($minut as $m){
    $result[]=$h.':'.$m;
   }        
 }
```

**Result**

```
$result=array('1:30','1:45','5:30','5:45');
```

Is there any other easiest way,Without using nested loop?

Comment: _All combinations?_ Can you brief it up ?

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran I updated my question with result

Comment: I'd say that is the proper way of solving the problem.

Comment: @Eric But $minut is looped many times

Answer (score 1):

You may use nested `array_map` in conjunction with `array_walk_recursive`:

```
$result = array();
array_walk_recursive(
    array_map(
        function ($h) use ($minut) {
            return array_map(
                function ($m) use ($h) { return $h.':'.$m; },
                $minut
            );
        },
        $hour
    ),
    function($v, $k) use($key, &$result){
        array_push($result, $v);
    }
);
```